# Spring Boot 2.3 Maven Docker build adds "docker.io" prefix

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to build a Docker image for my Spring Boot service using `mvn spring-boot:build-image` as [mentioned in the guide here](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/). It also mentions

> The result is an image called docker.io//:latest by default. You can modify the image name in Maven using

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <name>my/preferred/name</name>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It seems pretty straightforward... however, this results in a Docker image with the name `docker.io/my/preferred/name`.

How do I get rid of the `docker.io` prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are confusing the parser with so many slashes (`/`). Since there is no reasonable way to parse `my/preferred/name`, it will be considered as just a name (as a whole) in which case the default `docker.io/library/` will be prepended to it.

Here is how you can specify the name of the image in the `name` tag.

- **name (maps to docker.io/library/name)**
- domain/name
- domain:port/name
- domain:port/name:tag
- domain:port/name@digest

Your `my/preferred/name` name falls under the first category.

Comment: But it doesn't add `docker.io/library`, the result is `docker.io/my/preferred/name`.

Comment: And have you tried to use some normal name? Because the one with 2 slashes in it is not a valid image name. There should be at most one slash separating registry address (URL or IP optionally with port) from the name portion of the image.

Comment: I did try `my_preferred/name` now; same issue, `docker.io` is still prepended.

Comment: Disregard my last comment: the maven log output states "Successfully built image 'docker.io/my-preferred/name:latest'", but the image name in Docker is actually `my-preferred/name:latest`. So thank you, it works.